# Sum js file args in Node using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reduce

I'm trying to get arguments ( fom second arg ) when running a js file in node then sum them.

```
var args = 0;

process.argv.reduce((a, b, c) => {
    if (c > 1) {
        console.log(+a + +b);
        this.args += +a + +b;
    }
    return a
}, 0);
console.log(args)
```

In result I get **0** as sum when I run node `exlearnyounode.js 12 4 6` but I'm expecting **22**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are assuming `a` to be *accumulator*, `b` to be the element from collection, `c` to be the *index* of the element. Instead, you should just pass just two arguments to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), first is the accumulator, next is the element yielded from collection `process.argv`; it doesn't give the *index* relative to the collection.

This should do it:

```
console.log(process.argv.slice(1).reduce((acc, a) => acc + a))
```

`slice(1)` will give the arguments except first:

```js
var arr = [0, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(arr.slice(1))
console.log(arr.slice(1).reduce((acc, a) => acc + a))
```